# Gmail: add signature when replying to email

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail signature that says Best regards, because I don't want to keep typing it. But it doesn't show when replying to email, only when writing new ones. Can that be fixed?

And is it possible to add a full template, with a header too, that says Hi x for example? This is not that important, just asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature is definitely there in replies but it is at the bottom of complete email body. And the reason is you must have not the check the box below the signature which says: `Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it.`

Check this box (as shown in below screenshot), it will solve your problem:

[image]

And yes, it's possible to add full template, you can format your message by adding an image or changing the text style.

For more details see the Gmail Help page for [Create a Gmail signature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8395?hl=en).

Comment: I didn't find how to add a header `hi,` then the text, then the footer `best regards`, it seems that signatures only add a footer

Comment: In this example, you will want to use a Canned response. https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/tips/gmail/#!/show-tip/create-multiple-signatures-using-canned-responses